# Complex rails SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

First of all, a user has many age_demographics. An AgeDemographic object looks like this:

```
#<AgeDemographic id: 4384, user_id: 799, range: "35 - 49", percentage: 3.2, created_at: "2015-05-22 04:17:10", updated_at: "2015-05-22 04:17:10">
```

I'm building a user search tool where someone will select multiple age ranges that they want to target (`"12 - 17"` and `"18 - 24"` for example). I need to select users that have a collection of age demographic objects with a total percentage greater than `50%`.

This is what I've started with:

```
 User.joins(:age_demographics).where("age_demographics.range IN (?)", ["12 - 17", "18 - 24", "25 - 34"])
```

But I can't figure out how to tie in the sum of the percentages of those age_demographics into that where clause.

Let me know if this makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `having` and `group` methods for this:

```
User.joins(:age_demographics)
    .where("age_demographics.range IN (?)", ["12 - 17", "18 - 24", "25 - 34"])
    .group("users.id")
    .having("sum(percentage) >= 50")
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I add this into the SQL query?

Comment: @user3826547: What do you mean? Raw sql? Or in Rails (just add this after `where` method)?

Comment: This is just one part of a fairly complex search. I'm creating conditions (such as ["users.age >= ?", influencer_age_min]) and then joining them into a single string query. Similar to how it's done in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form.

Comment: @user3826547: Can you just try it? It really doesn't affect your `where` clause.

Comment: I get the error 'column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'

Comment: @user3826547: change `user_id` in the `group` to `id`